# Sum values in an multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to sum the values of the following array
I would like to group the same items by cumulating them, the output format would also be an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => R421_FD03
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => R421_FD03
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => R421_FD03
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => R421_FD02
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I tested this code but the result is not the one I'm waiting for:

```
$sumArray = array();

        array_walk_recursive($data, function($item, $key) use (&$sumArray){
            $sumArray[$key] = isset($sumArray[$key]) ?  $item + $sumArray[$key] : $item;
        });
```

The result I'm waiting for is this one

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => R421_FD03
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => R421_FD02
            [1] => 1
        )

     )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply simple `foreach()` with `array_values()`

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($array as $arr){
    foreach($arr as $ar){
        $final_array[$ar[0]][0] = $ar[0];
        $final_array[$ar[0]][1] = (isset($final_array[$ar[0]][1])) ?  $final_array[$ar[0]][1] + $ar[1] : $ar[1];
    }

}

$final_array = array_values($final_array);
print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/lABWG

Comment: @Jean glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge` with splat operator and then iterate through the array

```
$merged = array_merge(...$arr);//splat operator
$r = [];
array_walk($merged, function($v,$k) use(&$r){
 array_key_exists($v['0'], $r) ? ($r[$v[0]] += $v['1']) : ($r[$v[0]] = $v[1]);
});
print_r($r);
```

Result :-

```
Array
(
 [R421_FD03] => 3
 [R421_FD02] => 1
)
```